# Denied Canadian ETA because of my purpose of travel and ties to my country of residence. How should I reapply?

Tags: visas, canada, visa-refusals, nigerian-citizens

I was denied an ETA application into Canada because of my purpose of travel and ties to Canada or country of residence.

I am a 20 year old engineering student in Turkey who has been to America on tour before. I want to apply for visa to tour Canada for two weeks in January. 
The only tie I have here is an educational tie.

Will it help if I reapply with a letter from my university here and also an invitation from a Canadian resident? Or is it better if I return to my home country Nigeria and re-apply.

Comment: I do not understand how your American tour has any interest for this question.

Comment: @Vince Having held a US visa and having followed its terms, including leaving on time, would be positive travel history.

Answer (score 3):

First off being a Nigerian citizen, you are not eligible for an ETA to Canada unless you are a US Permanent Resident, which it would appear you are not.

For a visitors visa as a student, it is pretty standard that you get a letter from your school indicating you're enrolled and that the duration of visit will not affect your studies.

If you're going as a tourist as you indicate, you don't need an invitation letter from a resident of Canada. You will need hotel bookings, proof of having booked a tour with a tour company (if that is your mode of tourism), etc

Finally as to whether it is better to apply from Turkey or Nigeria, it shouldn't make a difference. As a student in Turkey you are allowed to apply from Turkey per the Canadian Government website. You can apply online or using paper. See [below](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1017&top=16):

> If you are applying on paper we recommend that you apply for a visa
> from your home country. **However, if you are legally admitted to the
> country you are currently in, you can apply at your nearest visa
> application centre (VAC).** The VAC can help make sure your
> application is complete and that all proper documentation is included.
> **You must state clearly on your application why you have not applied in your normal country of residence**.

**Supporting Documents**

> Travel History
>
> Passport
>
> Proof of Financial Resource of Supporter
>
> Proof of Means of Financial Support
>
> Digital photo
>
> Purpose of Travel
>
> Family Information (IMM5645)